# Drop row with bad data in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have at least one row with potentially bad data. I'd like to identify rows with bad data and entirely drop the row. Here's a pattern I have observed in a fairly large dataframe - `50k x 200`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'name': ['12 x st', '0.5555', 'y'], 
                   'val': [1, 0.5555, 2],
                   'col': ['t', 'u', '0.5555'],
                   'z': [2500, 2000, 1800]
                 })
```

The column type is `dtype('O')`. I'd like to remove the row with `0.5555`. Note that in columns `name` and `col` this is of type `str`. Not all columns have the bad value, but when it does it's in at least in a few columns.

The value is numeric and could be anything of type `float`.

Expected output is to completely drop the row with bad data that clearly doesn't match the format of the column.

Comment: Please [edit] to include your expected output and code for what you've tried based on your own research so that we cna better understand how to answer

Answer (score 1):

If the valid values are only going to be letter characters, you could do something as simple as this filter, which checks if all of the characters in each value are alphabetic.

```py
df = df[df['name'].str.isalpha()]
```

```
  name  val     col     z
2    y  2.0  0.5555  1800
```

and do the same for column 'col'.

However, if there's the chance that a valid value contains *both* numbers and letters (something like "I bought 5 bananas"), the above wouldn't work, nor would substituting the `isalpha()` method for `isalphanum()`, since `isalphanum()` returns true if the characters are alphabetic *or* numeric.

My approach to that situation would be a custom validator function that tries to cast the value to an float and returns False if possible.

```py
def is_string(s):
    try:
        float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df = df[df['name'].apply(is_string)]
```

```
      name  val     col     z
0  12 x st  1.0       t  2500
2        y  2.0  0.5555  1800
```

Then, to apply this to all string columns, you could do:

```py
for col in df.select_dtypes('O'):
    df = df[df[col].apply(is_string)]
```

```
      name  val col     z
0  12 x st  1.0   t  2500
```

A more concise way to express this might be:

```py
df = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.apply(is_string)] if x.dtypes == 'O' else x, axis=0)
df = df.dropna(how='any', axis=0)
```

Comment: this works. can you explain how the boolean return from the function `is_string` drop the rows? I was expecting 1 row to be dropped from my real df but it dropped 10. when i sort df by ascending I only see 1 row with numeric.

Comment: Sure thing. Any time you apply a mask to a DataFrame, under the hood it is returning a DataFrame of boolean values the exact same shape as your original DataFrame. Then the mask removes the `False` values while keeping the `True` values.  One thing I realized after my original answer (that I've updated) is that you only want to apply this to string-type columns. If you apply it to other-type columns, it will return `False` where you want it to be `True`.

Comment: More specifically, in the case of my function, for columns that are string-types, it tries to convert each value to a float. If it succeeds, you know that value doesn't belong in there since it's a numeric. If it fails, you assume it is a string, so it returns True.